# My app displays half when it runs on my phone used as an emulator

Tags: android

here is the app displaying half. The email field and Login textview arent there

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @yuseph add your xml code

Comment: I think you but your views each other can you please add some xml code in the question?

Comment: Here is the xml file

Comment: Try removing the margin from `button`. It looks like the button's margin is pushing all other views away.

Answer (score 1):

You might have selected wrong device when you are Designing your Layout that's why they must have jumped off of the screen when  you run your app on your device. Select your current device from **Design view** when you Design your layout. 
Or have a look at the constraint you have provided to your widgets, either they are correct or not. Most of the time this problem occurs when you don't provide constraints to particular widgets or may have provided wrong constraints, they jumps away from the screen. 
For the simplicity i suggest you to use **Linear layout** and set orientation as *vertical* then you don't have to worry about constraints.
Thank You!