# Button Stuck on the Top

Tags: android

this is my first time using Android Studio and I am running into an issue. I created a new screen for an app I am working on and I inserted a button. Usually, buttons stay where you put them but this button went straight to the top. What could be the root cause?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlhLp.png)

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Android studio drag drop doesn't work that way. It depends in your layout

Comment: Try adding constraints to your button. https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout might point you to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said this is your first time on android studio, so let's start as a beginner. According to screenshot you have posted you've used *linear layout* and linear layout works according to the orientation you provides. If orientation is set to vertical, simply means all the newly added widgets will place one after the other vertically, if horizontal it will place horizontally if you provide no orientation you will have little bad intended widgets layout simply mean all the widget will be upon each other at any one part of your layoutor at the top of your layout. If you wanna see where to set orientation go to **text** portion as you can see in your screen shot which is where you code your **XML** then inside your Linear Layout tag which will be like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"> <!--In my case it is vertical-->
</LinearLayout>
```

This means every widget you add in your linear layout it will be start adding from the top of the layout and goes further one after the other vertically . 
And Like you said, Normally it happens when you add widget it stays there where you place it in design view, yes that's true. To achieve this You have to use something called **Constraints layout** you add widgets and have to give some constraints to them so they can not jumps off of the screen, Here is little explanation of why sometimes widgets act weird when you run your app while using constraint layout
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58935608/12397978

If you still wanna use Constraint layout change your *Linear layout* tag to constraint layout and remove orientation, like so:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/resView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Below four lines are constraints which simply means this widget will be connected to its parent layout from every side

```
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

Tip: Furthermore I suggest you to do little research about **Constraint layout**, **Linear Layout** and **Relative layout** in android studio.
I hope this helps, ThankYou.

Comment: Thanks!!! This helps a lot. As a beginner in android studio, I need all get and I appreciate you taking the time to explain it.

Comment: If this answer helps you, kindly check(tick). It will be helpful for other readers as well. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

It'll depend on the parent View of your new view (`Button`). Your layout are using `LinearLayout` for the root, it will arrange child views from top to bottom or left to right depend on its orientation.
You should learn about different kinds of `ViewGroup` before working with the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Your root / top level view group or container is Linear layout with vertical orientation. If you'd like your view to center in between, try providing "layout_gravity = center" for your root linear layout and "gravity = center" for the view that you're dropping in the xml

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot, you are using Linearlayout as parent layout, whose behaviour is like **whatever view you push into your layout, it will align all children in a single direction, vertically or horizontally**.

It means Linearlayout will align your childs from **TOP TO BOTTOM if your orientation is vertical** and from **LEFT TO RIGHT if your orientation is horizontal.**

For more information on Linearlayout, [Visit this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear)